# How to set dd/mm/yy for command-prompt in zsh?

Tags: debian, zsh, date, prompt

I am on zsh (not using oh-my-zsh) and want to have a custom command prompt.

Currently it just gives the hostname and % as command prompt -

```
[code]
think-debian% hostname
think-debian
[/code]
```

what I want to do is to have -

```
[username/userid@hostname] - [pwd]-[ DD/MM/YY local time in hh:mm:ss] $
```

how do I manage that ?

I do see the clue in man zshmisc

and specifically in EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES

> EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES
>          Prompt sequences undergo a special form of expansion.  This type of expansion is also available using the -P option to the print
>   builtin.
>
> ```
>    If the PROMPT_SUBST option is set, the prompt string is first subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution and arithmetic
> ```
>
> expansion.  See zshexpn(1).
>
> ```
>    Certain escape sequences may be recognised in the prompt string.
>
>    If  the  PROMPT_BANG  option is set, a `!' in the prompt is replaced by the current history event number.  A literal `!' may then
> ```
>
> be represented as `!!'.
>
> ```
>    If the PROMPT_PERCENT option is set, certain escape sequences that start with `%' are expanded.  Many escapes  are  followed  by  a
> ```
>
> single  character,  although  some  of  these  take  an  optional
>   integer argument that should appear between the `%' and the next
>   character of the sequence.  More complicated escape sequences are
>   available to provide conditional expansion.
>
> SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES    Special characters
>          %%     A `%'.
>
> ```
>    %)     A `)'.
> ```
>
> Login information
>          %l     The line (tty) the user is logged in on, without `/dev/' prefix.  If the name starts with`/dev/tty', that prefix is stripped.
>
> ```
>    %M     The full machine hostname.
> ```
>
> %m     The hostname up to the first `.'.  An integer may follow the`
>   %' to specify how many components of the hostname are desired.  With
>   a negative integer, trailing components of the hostname are shown.
>
> ```
>    %n     $USERNAME.
>
>    %y     The line (tty) the user is logged in on, without `/dev/' prefix.  This does not treat `/dev/tty' names specially.
> ```
>
> Shell state
>          %#     A  `#' if the shell is running with privileges, a`%' if not.  Equivalent to `%(!.#.%%)'.  The definition of`privileged', for
>   these purposes, is that either the effective user ID is zero, or, if
>   POSIX.1e capabilities are supported, that at least one capability  is
>   raised in either the Effective or Inheritable capability vectors.
>
> ```
>    %?     The return status of the last command executed just before the prompt.
>
>    %_     The  status  of  the parser, i.e. the shell constructs (like `if' and `for') that have been started on the command line. If
> ```
>
> given an integer number that many strings will be printed; zero or
>   negative or no integer means print as many as there  are.   This  is 
>   most useful  in  prompts  PS2  for  continuation lines and PS4 for
>   debugging with the XTRACE option; in the latter case it will also work
>   non-interactively.
>
> %^     The status of the parser in reverse. This is the same as `%_'
>   other than the order of strings.  It is often used in RPS2.
>
> ```
>    %d
>    %/     Current working directory.  If an integer follows the `%', it specifies a number of  trailing  components  of  the  current
> ```
>
> working directory to show; zero means the whole path.  A negative
>   integer specifies leading components, i.e. %-1d specifies the first
>   component.
>
> Date and time
>          %D     The date in yy-mm-dd format.
>
> ```
>    %T     Current time of day, in 24-hour format.
>
>    %t
>    %@     Current time of day, in 12-hour, am/pm format.
>
>    %*     Current time of day in 24-hour format, with seconds.
>
>    %w     The date in day-dd format.
>
>    %W     The date in mm/dd/yy format.
> ```

I tried quite a few ways but unable to get it in dd/Month/yy -

```
think-debian%PS1=%n@%m-%/\ %D\ %*\ $

shirish@think-debian-/home/shirish 16-12-19 12:33:27 $ PS1=%n@%m-%/\ %W\ %*\ $

shirish@think-debian-/home/shirish 12/19/16 12:33:55 $
```

Update - Have come very close with -

```
$PS1=%n@%m-%/\ %D{%d/%m/%y}\ %*\ $
 shirish@think-debian-/home/shirish 19/12/16 17:31:09 $
```

Looking forward to know

Running zsh version 5.2

Answer (score 5):

For the date/time part in the format `DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS`, you can use the following:

`%D{%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S}`

[**Reference**](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html)

`%D{string}`: string is formatted using the strftime function. ...

Comment: you are very near, just near a bit more,  if you can  wing it, wing it please.